# WPF Load resources via PRISM

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a WPF application that is being written using PRISM. I want a way to allow it to be "re-branded" easily. So I started to create a module, that when initialized added resource dictionaries to the application. This worked until I wanted to style some of the components directly in the shell.xaml. The module is not initialized when the xaml is parsed so it errors.

I know I could reference a resource using the application:/// syntax but that then forces the styling dll to be named a specific name, which I am not fond of.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is waaaay after the fact but it is what I'm planning for my current project, using MEF. It does not have to be a module.

This is the interface

```
[InheritedImport]
public interface IBrandProvider
{
    ResourceDictionary ProvideResources();
}
```

Implementations will load a resource dictionary using the pack URI syntax that you already alluded to. Implementation on your shell might look like this;

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MainWindow(IBrandProvider brand)
{
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(brand.ProvideResources());
}
```

Ensure that your `IBrandProvider` is in your Container (Unity or MEF) and make sure you use it somewhere. BOOM, you are good to go. As you might expect, this is not possible or even desirable in XAML.

For extra flavour, the interface could return a value stating what level you want the resources automatically applied - application, shell or none (with a key so you can cherry pick them later perhaps).